# Wireless network adapter not detected on start

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I have to turn the wireless network switch off and on again every time Ubuntu starts up in order to recognize the wireless adapter.

The laptop model is IBM Thinkpad R60 series. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and all working fine except for the problem i mentioned above. The wireless chipset obtained from the command `lspci` is:

```
Atheros Communications Inc. AR5212 802.11abg NIC (rev 01)
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: The purpose on this is to save the planet, ie to shut down the device you don't need (i'm joking). 
To get some help i suggest you to give the community some technical specs.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo su
echo ath5k >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Does it work now?